# how can I get table row data with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a table as follows:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="layui-table">
    <tbody>
    <tr data-index="0" class="">
        <td data-field="sid" data-content="123456">
            <div class="layui-table-cell laytable-cell-1-sid"> 123456 </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-index="1" class="">
        <td data-field="sid" data-content="100012">
            <div class="layui-table-cell laytable-cell-1-sid"> 100012 </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I can use the following scripts to get `tbody` but not `tr` or `td`

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    var tb = $('.layui-table-main table:eq(0) tbody');
    console.log(tb);
    var size=tb.find("tr").length;
    console.log(size);
});
```

What I have been trying to do is to get each `td`'s value. How can I get them?

Comment: why not use the class of the table? like `var tb = $('.layui-table:eq(0) tbody');`

Comment: One thing to mention: the table is generated via `jquery.table.rowspan.js`. The provided answers are not able to get the right results.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the list of `tr` using `.find("tr")` on the `tbody` and then loop through the result to get each row. Within that loop, you can find the list of `td` using `.find("td")` on each `row`. See the implementation below.

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
  var tb = $('.layui-table:eq(0) tbody');
  var size = tb.find("tr").length;
  console.log("Number of rows : " + size);
  tb.find("tr").each(function(index, element) {
    var colSize = $(element).find('td').length;
    console.log("  Number of cols in row " + (index + 1) + " : " + colSize);
    $(element).find('td').each(function(index, element) {
      var colVal = $(element).text();
      console.log("    Value in col " + (index + 1) + " : " + colVal.trim());
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="layui-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr data-index="0" class="">
      <td data-field="sid" data-content="123456">
        <div class="layui-table-cell laytable-cell-1-sid"> 123456 </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-index="1" class="">
      <td data-field="sid" data-content="100012">
        <div class="layui-table-cell laytable-cell-1-sid"> 100012 </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: your code is ok to understand. But I still got number of rows = 0.

Comment: Just run the code snippet and see the result yourself. If this doesn't solve your issue, you have some issue that is not covered in this question.

Comment: thanks for the response. I update my original post. the difference is that the table is not static one, but is generated from jquery.

Comment: Add the code that generates the table to the question please.

Comment: can anyone help me out?

Comment: Can you please create a different question for the issue mentioned in the last comment? The issue specified in this question is covered in this answer. The comments section is not a good place to ask new question.